Телграмм бот на aiogram не работает оплата в лайв режиме
Запускал платёжку через API Юкасса, в тестовом режиме платёж работает, как получил настоящий секретный ключ и id магазина, перестало работать и выдаёт такую ошибку:
HTTPError: 400 Client Error:  for url: https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments
Traceback (most recent call last):

 
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectaiogramm/payment.py", line 15, in create
    payment = Payment.create({
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectaiogramm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/yookassa/payment.py", line 66, in create
    response = instance.client.request(HttpVerb.POST, path, None, headers, params_object)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectaiogramm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/yookassa/client.py", line 51, in request
    raw_response = self.execute(body, method, path, query_params, request_headers)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectaiogramm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/yookassa/client.py", line 82, in execute
    self.log_response(raw_response.content, self.get_response_info(raw_response), raw_response.headers)
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectaiogramm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/yookassa/client.py", line 169, in get_response_info
    "raise_for_status": response.raise_for_status(),
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error:  for url: https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments

При переходе на сайт выдает это:
{
  "type" : "error",
  "id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "code" : "invalid_credentials",
  "description" : "Incorrect password format in the Authorization header. Use Secret key issued in Merchant Profile as the password",
  "parameter" : "Authorization"
}

Код платёжки:
import yookassa
from yookassa import Payment
import uuid
from config import ACCOUNT_ID, SECRET_KEY


yookassa.Configuration.account_id = ACCOUNT_ID
yookassa.Configuration.secret_key = SECRET_KEY


def create(amount, chat_id):
   id_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
   payment = Payment.create({
       "amount": {
           'value':amount,
           'currency': "RUB"
       },
       'payment_metod_data': {
           'type': 'bank_card',

       },
       'confirmation': {
           'type': 'redirect',
           'return_url': 'https://xxxxxxxx'
       },
       'capture': True,
       'metadata': {
           'chat_id': chat_id
       },
       'description': 'Оплата подписки'
   }, id_key)

   return payment.confirmation.confirmation_url, payment.id


Incorrect password format in the Authorization header. Use Secret key issued in Merchant Profile as the password

Решено. Проблема связана в чеках. надо было отключить авто отправку чека в ЛК юкассы.

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
